WiX Installer - what will stop logs being created?
We have an installer created with WiX which for some reason has stopped logging when a major upgrade is performed (i.e. the logs created in the standard windows %temp% directory). If a clean install is performed then the usual logs are created as you would expect.
What conditions may cause this to happen?
I've previously added verbose logging to the MSI project(s) to see if this changed the situation but alas not.
<Property Id="MSILOGGING" Value="v" />

The MSIs are included in a bootstrapper, and I have explicitly "not disabled" (I hate this logic!) logging within the bundle which contains the MSI projects
<Log Disable="no"/>

WiX 3.14 using the Wix Toolset Visual Studio extension. There are a number of MSIs in a bootstrapper, but no logs are created for any of them (i.e. lack of logging is not limited to one MSI).
For info during the upgrade, the bootstrapper process is launched in passive mode as follows:
 Bootstrapper.exe /passive


OK, I've got a workaround though it's not really the solution I was after (as it had been working without the workaround!).
Adding the -log switch (with a log file otherwise it doesn't even seem to run) seems to do the trick, though also specifying it to be in the %temp% directory where it should be has the effect of only creating a log for the bootstrapper but not for each of the MSI's within, but it'll do for now.
Bootstrapper.exe /passive -log installer.log

